# minimizing the calculation time (ie: "print" slows it down)

Tags: python, algorithm

I have simple fibonacci(n) function that returns the n-th value. The main() code is as follows:

```
def main():
# Programming 101, basic recursion
  start = time.clock()
  for i in range(36):
      print fibonacci(i)
  end = time.clock()
  print "Time elapsed = ", end - start, "seconds"

# Basic tweak no.1
  start2 = time.clock()
  list_fib = []
  for i in range(36):
      list_fib.append(fibonacci(i))
  print list_fib
  end2 = time.clock()
  print "Time elapsed = ", end2 - start2, "seconds"
```

The typical output on Windows & Linux:

```
....
9227465
Time elapsed =  0.246583058361 seconds
[0, 1, 1, ....
Time elapsed =  0.00865510658878 seconds
```

**Question**: Is there a HOWTO or guideline for Python's numerical recipes? In my example, the "print" loop is quite costly and should be avoided.

Comment: `i/o` is always expensive, unless redirect `std.out` to `dev/null` that is

Comment: what do you mean with numerical recipes ? A book on algorithms ? You can check numpy and scipy documentation for fast number crunching procedures

Comment: Note: A more detailed output can be obtained via `import cProfile` and executing `cProfile.run('main()')`

Comment: Don't write code to do boring things like building lists. Let Python do it for you: `print [fibonacci(i) for i in range(36)]`.

Comment: @Karl: interestingly, the set generator is slower than my tweaked code. Weird huh? Shorter code, longer execution.

Comment: @Karl: retested, set generator slightly faster. I tried with `main();main2();main();main2()` - the first call is slower in all combination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save you data by appending it in a list. Then print it in one shot as you did in your second example. This is a common idiom in python. Often you use something like:

```
print '\n'.join(milistofdatastrings)
```

You have a collection of [scipy performance tips here](http://www.scipy.org/PerformanceTips). I also like this compedium of [numpy functions and examples](http://www.scipy.org/Numpy_Example_List_With_Doc).

Although not specifically numerical, you have a collection of [python tricks for performance](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonSpeed/PerformanceTips).

Comment: Interestingly, it was through numpy libraries which led me to this question and some tricks like above is mentioned in SO. Wanted to know if someone compiled a list of these "tricks".

Comment: Thanks for quick response, voting to close this page (is this the right way?)

Comment: @Alvin K. The option to close a page is in the bottom of your question window amid "link|edit|close|flag". If you are refering to this, you should not vote to close. You just upvote the answer (up and down arrows here at the top left) and/or select it as the best answer (green mark below the upvotes).